# extract a frame from a flash movie

Tags: flash, frame, movie

I have a flash player playing a .flv video file

How could I reproduce this behaviour :
when client press stop, catch the current frame ; kill the player ; display the last frame (previously caught) instead

Any solution would be fine (AS, PHP, JS, etc.), though it cannot be only server sided because I don't know in advance what frame will be needed.

Comment: You could use Bitmap and BitmapData to capture any portion of the video and display it down the track - is this what you mean?

Comment: Do you mean stopping the player or jumping to the end of the movie?  What does 'previously caught' mean in this context?

Comment: stopping the player at the current frame. No matter how long into the movie you are. I basically just want a Print Screen of the last frame but dont know how to get it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simplified version:

```
var flv:FLVPlayback = new FLVPlayback();
var bmd:BitmapData = new BitmapData(flv.width, flv.height);
var bm:Bitmap;

function captureFrame():void {
    flv.stop();
    bmd.draw(flv);
    bm = new Bitmap(bmd);
    addChild(bm);
    // kill video and player here
}
```

Depending on where you're hosting the video, you may have some cross-domain issues with using BitmapData. But, assuming you have full control, this should work.

Comment: I will most certainly have a cross domain issue :P but that will be another workaround. Ill try it tomorrow, thanks